# How to deal with opinion based questions?

Tags: discussion

I am not sure how I should deal with some questions I have that may be considered opinion-based.

**Example**

I recently read [this reddit article](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/22ztqp/why_does_nerdtree_exist_whats_wrong_with_netrw/cgs4aax) about the shortcortcomings of netrw (bad code base leading to errors) that also pop up if you use extensions like tpope's [vim-vinegar](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar). I wonder now whether I should use [vimfiler](https://github.com/Shougo/vimfiler.vim) or [NERD Tree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) (with the non-drawer option set) and would appreciate the view of other experienced vim users on that topic.

I have the following options:

- I will not ask any question, as a question on this may be considered an opinion-based question that StackExchange does not like to see
- I will ask a clearly opinion-based question like *"Do you prefer vimfiler, vinegar or NERD Tree with non-drawer-flag set and why?"*, knowing that this question will likely be closed (but hoping it will get good answers as I have seen often on opinion-based questions)
- I will try to create a non-opinion based question for it like *"What are the most important feature differences between vimfiler, vinegar or NERD Tree with non-drawer-flag set and how fast and stable is their use?"*
- I will ask an opinion-based question in the chat and risk getting little answers (as no reputation is given) and knowing noone will ever reread a given answer in chat

How should I deal with this?

Comment: Related: http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1278/how-do-we-share-general-vim-experience-or-can-we

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to solve a problem, I assume? Such as quickly navigating in a project, or opening web pages, or something else.

*That* is your question, and netrw is *an* possible answer, as are vimfiler or NERDtree. And perhaps there is even another solution to your problem other than using a file manager plugin you haven't even thought of :-)

[How do I install a plugin in vim/vi?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/613/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-in-vim-vi?s=6%7C0.0000) is perhaps a good example of how such a question can be asked.

Comment: If I ask the question "how do I navigate in a project?" I might get netrw, NERDtree and vimfiler as answer, and possible other plugins or methods will be mentioned. But this does not really answer my real question which one I should use, on which I want the community's input :/

Comment: @cbaumhardt Which plugin you *should* use is a silly question anywhere. You **should** use the solution that you like the best, and no one else can decide that for you.